# Как настроить два проекта на Docker и Nginx на одном сервере?

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Пытаюсь на одном сервере под разными ip запустить два сайта на django.

Возникает ошибка, что порт занят. Исправил порты, но сайт не старартует.

Подскажите, где ошибка?

Ip работают, когда захожу по второму ip получаю переадресацию на первый сайт. Все настройки указал для второго сайта. В конце добавил настройку nginx первого сайта:

```
#Django
# Should be one of dev, prod
MODE=prod
PORT=8008

#postgres
DB_NAME=xxx
DB_USER=xxx
DB_HOST=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
DB_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword

#WSGI
WSGI_PORT=8008
WSGI_WORKERS=4
WSGI_LOG_LEVEL=debug

# Celery
CELERY_NUM_WORKERS=2

# Email
EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxxx
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: site_container
    restart: always
    command: ./commands/start_server.sh
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${WSGI_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands
      - static_content:/var/www/site
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
#    environment:
#      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_content:/var/www/site
    ports:
      - 81:80
      - 444:443
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  static_content: {}
```

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name 183.22.332.12;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/site;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/site;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8010;
    }
}
```

default.conf первый сайт:

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name site1 ip_site1;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1/chain.pem;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/artads;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/artads;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8008;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name ip_site2 site2;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/gdr_mr;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/gdr_mr;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8013;
    }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.site1 site1;

        location / {
                return 301 https://site1$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно сколько у вас контейнеров? В частности для nginx их два или один? Если два где докер конфигурация второго? Также добавьте в вопрос какая команда и какое точно сообщение об ошибке выдает

Comment: @RomanKonoval первая настройка абсолютно такая же, только разные ip и домены, остальные настройки такие-же, в первом docker-compose nginx 
    `ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443`

Comment: для контейнеров я привык использовать `traefik`  - обратный прокси. На одном сервере куча лендинга, но привязаны к разным контейнерам и доменам, пока не подводил

Comment: @ipatev_nn можете пожалуйста описать подробно этот вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет "правильного" запуска можно всегда и много спорить - ведь сколько людей, столько и мнений, но пример +- "удобной" и масштабируемой конфигурации опишу. Для "удобства" работы в такой конфигурации предложил бы установить https://nginxproxymanager.com/ в качестве реверс прокси и объединить контейнеры и nginxproxymanager в одну сеть - после чего появиться возможность прокидывать порты контейнеров по http(s), tcp, udp на внешний интерфейс при помощи GUI а так же еще ряд вских плюшек например как генерация SSL сертификатов и их авто продление

---

Сначала создадим саму сеть

```
docker network create --driver bridge --subnet 172.26.0.0/24 testnet
```

---

Настроим NPM (nginxproxymanager) - по умолчанию будем считать реверс прокси последним узлом сети, в итоге получим

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.254
    restart: always
    ports:
      # Public HTTP Port:
      - '80:80'
      # Public HTTPS Port:
      - '443:443'
      # Admin Web Port:
      - '81:81'
    environment:
      # These are the settings to access your db
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "172.26.0.253"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "user"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pwd"
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "npm"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx-proxy-manager:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.253
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pwd"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "npm"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pwd"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  testnet:
    external: true
```

---

И настроим сам контейнер

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: site_container
    restart: always
    command: ./commands/start_server.sh
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands
      - static_content:/var/www/site
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
#    environment:
#      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}

networks:
  testnet:
    external: true
volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  static_content: {}
```

---

После чего проводим первоначальную настройку NPM согласно инструкции https://nginxproxymanager.com/guide/#project-goal и добавляем хост

[image: Настройка домена]

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, мне нужно убрать настройку nginx из моих docker-compose файлов, а как тогда он будет слушать порты?

Comment: "Внешнее" порты слушает NPM и исходя из настроенных правил перенаправляет трафик на тот или иной (внутренний) ip контейнера. Исходя из вашего конфига предположил что на backend открыт порт для прослушания трафика (nginx был убран с вязи с тем что счел его прокси сервером для "одного" контейнера)

Comment: и настройка для letsencrypt будет для всех сайтов настроена? Тоесть мне нужно добавить сайты в nginx proxy master, и каким образом он будет переходить на порт 8013 к примеру для site1 и на 8008 для site2

Comment: Вы можете сами настраивать из GUI сайты которые будут по https, а какие по http, выпускать сертификаты letsencrypt, загружать свои или выбирать из ранее использованных. При этом сертификаты letsencrypt продляются автоматически. Перенаправление между сайтами происходит по доменным именам, то-есть вы вносите в список доменов site1 c 127.26.0.2:8013 и site2 c 127.26.0.2:8008

Comment: Спасибо, я сейчас проделаю этот путь, если будут вопросы, то я ещё Вас поспрашиваю если можно)

Comment: Мне нужно погасить все мои контейнера и ребилдить их уже с новыми настройками, правильно?

Comment: После правки файла достаточно выполнить docker compose up -d что пере соберет его

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129799/discussion-between-oleksandr-and-roman-tokarev).

Answer (score 2):

Вариант использования Traefik как обратный прокси:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    command:
      - "--api=true"
      - "--log.level=INFO"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=logs/access.log"
      - "--accesslog.bufferingsize=100"
      - "--global.sendanonymoususage"

      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.providersthrottleduration=10s"

      - "--certificatesresolvers.traefik-resolver.acme.email=user@domain.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.traefik-resolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.traefik-resolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"

      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.dashboard.address=:8000"

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"

      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=dashboard"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=auth"

      # Note: all dollar signs in the hash need to be doubled for escaping.
      # To create user:password pair, it's possible to use this command:
      # echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:1qwdqw@#dfw3423eda"

      # Redirect http to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirect-to-https.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirect-to-https.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirect-to-https.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The HTTP secure port
      - "443:443"
      - "9001:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./logs:/logs"
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      # So that Traefissk can listen to the Docker events
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      - traefik
    restart: always
```

Более подробно про настройки можно прочитать тут [Traefik на dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik)

Перед запуском нужно будет создать контейнерную сеть Traefik и запустить сам контейнер командой `docker-compose up -d` в каталоге с файлом выше.

Далее в контейнере приложения прописываем:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
...
services:
  nameyouservice:
  ...
    networks:
      - traefik
  ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      - "traefik.http.routers.uniqhabname.rule=Host(`yourdomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.uniqhabname.entrypoints=https,wss"
      - "traefik.http.routers.uniqhabname.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.uniqhabname.tls.certresolver=traefik-resolver"
   ...
```

Заменяем `uniqhabname` на понятное имя, чтобы потом по логам можно было понять, чье перенаправление, и указываем `yourdomain.com` при обращении на чье имя будет перенаправление в данный контейнер. То есть, на одном ip может быть много сервисов и перенаправление на нужный будет по имени.